# Appropriate use case of __get in daily life programming

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

I am in learning phase of OOP and PHP. Below is how i implemented __get method. It is working fine but i don't understand why to use it. Since in my example i set the property to protected deliberately so that i can't be accessed via outside class. Then what is the purpose of __get then ?

```
class Magic {
    protected $name = 'John';
    public $age = 26;
    public $new_name;

    public function __get($key){
        $this->new_name = $key;
    }

    public function get_new_name(){
        return $this->new_name. " is my friend";
    }
}

$person = new Magic();
$person->Alan;
echo $person->get_new_name();
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't implement a setter?

Comment: I've never seen it used that way, pretty interesting use case but not very IDE compatible.  I normally use it in combination with `__set()` for undeclared properties if I need special characteristics for when I set a property.  Then that undeclared property can be defined in PHPDoc using `@property` so it is still compatible with IDEs.

Comment: @Grice `__set()` would have been called if he put `$person->undeclaredProperty = 'Alan';`.  He is using `__get()` but it is not a common use by any means.

Comment: so my question is what should be the appropriate use case as in all the blogs i read about it says that it is being called when a property is not public or not exists. Why one should call a property outside of class when he himself has not declared it to be accessible.

Comment: @Devon Your right, I see it now. I just quickly went over the code and it looked like he was trying to implement a setter. Never seen someone implement get that way.

Comment: you guyz discussed high level programming and didn't clear my confusion :)

Comment: @RaheelKhan did you read http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php ?  What I said should have made sense if you had a basic understanding of __get and __set.  For that you need to turn to the manual.

Comment: `Below is how i implemented __get method` but you ask `what is the purpose of __get then ?` something I don't understand here... why have you written it like that in the first place?

Comment: I am in a concept that we have to use get when accessing undeclared or non public property. So i implemented it that way. And what i wanted to ask that in every day programming where can i utitlize _get as the basic purpose seems of no use to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no valid reason I would have thought of that you would use `__get()` with a protected string, protected arrays would be useful, but not strings.  The example you provided works, but it isn't going to be the best code for others to understand or for use with IDEs (code editors).

Since you don't seem to understand what I was saying, here is an example of a quick database script.

Let's say you want to insert a row in the database using an ORM-like class.  You would do something like:

```
Class Person {
  protected $fields = array();
  public function setField($name, $value) {
    $this->fields[$name] = $value;
  }
  public function getField($name) {
    return $this->fields[$name];
  }
  public function save() {
    Database::insert($table, $fields);  // Generic function to insert the row, don't worry about this.
  }
}
```

Now in this instance you could do:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->setField('name', 'Bob');
$person->setField('age', '30');
$person->save();

echo $person->getField('name'); // Echoes Bob
```

### Overloading

Now to change this, we could use overloading with `__set()` instead of `setField()` and `__get()` instead of `getField()`:

```
Class Person {
  protected $fields = array();
  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->fields[$name] = $value;
  }
  public function __get($name) {
   return $this->fields[$name];
  }
  public function save() {
    Database::insert($table, $fields);
  }
}
```

Now in this instance you could do:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->name =  'Bob';
$person->age = '30';
$person->save();

echo $person->name; // Echoes Bob
```

Hopefully this gives you an easy example of how overloading can work.  We don't want to declare the properties `$name` and `$age` because we want to use those properties to build the `$fields` array which is later used in the insert.

Comment: @RaheelKhan, yes, it was the most comprehensive example of overloading I could write up in ~10 minutes.

Comment: thank you so much ! It will help other ppl too who grab things by real use cases like me !

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use the __get method for obtain the value of an array. In this case you can have a dynamic number of class variable.

```
public function __get($key){
    return $this->property[$key];
}
```